# Antd Autocomplete options: NVDA announces 'blank' instead of text

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, antd

I'm using Antd Autocomplete options to populate recent searches on a search bar like this:

`
//substituting process with dummy data for stackoverflow

```
const recentSearches = [
  { label: "hello", value: "hello" },
  { label: "codesandbox", value: "codesandbox" },
  { label: "react", value: "react" },
];

const getOptions = () => {
      return [
        {
          label: <p className="captionText">{GetLabel("lblMyRecentSearches")}</p>,
          options: recentSearches,
        },
      ];
 };

return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item name="">
        <AutoComplete
          options={ getOptions }
          //more events
        </AutoComplete>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
   );
```

`
This populates the recent searches under the search bar

However when I open up NVDA and press arrow down to navigate on the options NVDA announces 'blank' instead of the text. I tried adding role = option and aria-label, nothing worked. Any ideas how to make these options accessible with NVDA?